# How to fix the error "The target polymorphic type "components_COMPNENT_NAME is not one of the defined target types"

Tags: strapi

I successfully updated the component using the `PUT` command, and after that Strapi threw the error:

> Error: The target polymorphic type "components_COMPONENT_NAME" is
>   not one of the defined target types

The command I used to update the Strapi component:

**PUT** http://localhost:1337/content-type-builder/components/COMPONENT_DIR.COMPONENT_NAME

```
{
    "components": [],
    "component": {
        "category": "COMPONENT_DIR",
        "icon": "biohazard",
        "name": "COMPONENT_NAME",
        "description": "",
        "connection": "default",
        "collectionName": "components_COMPONENT_DIR_COMPONENT_NAME",
        "attributes": {
            "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "default": ""
            },
            "uuid": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "banner_image": {
                "type": "media",
                "multiple": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! can you please provide steps to reproduce your issue. Thank you.

Comment: You can reproduce it when you remove "compoments" or "components_COMPONENT_DIR_COMPONENT_NAME". I think you should add some picture for it before. And it still exist in upload_file_morph table (I use mysql)

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly the same issue, but I also got this error because of the media-library. I created a collection type which used certain images from the media library, afterwards I deleted this collection, which resulted in an error for all related images because the collection wasn't accessible anymore and Strapi threw this error.

I had to recreate the collection type with the same name, then delete all related images, delete the collection and then upload the images again...

It seems like this is an error with the media library-plugin, which should delete these relations if you delete some content of specific components or collections.

Comment: this fixed my issue step by step!

Answer (score 2):

This error appeared for me, when I renamed a collection type and everything that comes with it (display name, collection name, routes, config, controllers, config, services).

After I did that, the data was not displayed anymore in the `Strapi` admin dashboard. As I then tried to re-uploaded some of the media I got that error:

```
Error: The target polymorphic type "old_collection_type_name" is not one of the defined target types
```

The media still was inside the folder `my_root_project/public/uploads`, it just didn't show up in dashboard. After I deleted the `uploads` folders content, the error was gone.

I hope this info helps somebody.

Comment: I had this error and I just manually deleted records that matched the old relationship type (matching "old_collection_type_name") in the "field" field from the "upload_file_morph" table. Much quicker fix.

Answer (score 1):

I found in the stripe table uploaded_file morph column related type registers associating a uploaded_file with the component deleted. I remove theses registers and everything worked just fine again.

Comment: Where is the "striped table uploaded_file morph column" please?

Comment: Maybe my spelling is wrong .
I mean table upload_file_morph and column related_type. Also, I'm using postgres. Maybe help.
I found registers where the value of related_type was a deleted component. So I deleted the registers.